# abelian group as Z module

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

How Would you prove that every abelian group can be understood as a Z-Module in a unique way?

I would guess that you would have to prove its bijective, but not sure how to go about this

Comment: What is the definition of a $\mathbb Z$-module?

Answer (score 6):

Given an abelian group $G$ its set of endomorphisms
$$
{\rm End}(G)=\{f:G\rightarrow G,\text{homomorphism}\}
$$
is a ring under the usual operations of sum and composition, with unity the identity map.

Given any ring with unity $R$ there is a unique map of unital rings
$$
\Bbb Z\longrightarrow R
$$
given by $n\mapsto n\cdot1_R$ with the usual convention for $n<0$ (preserving the identity mandates $1_{\Bbb Z}\mapsto 1_R$). By applying this to ${\rm End}(G)$ you immediately see that $G$ has a unique structure of $\Bbb Z$-module.